# How to change from ID to class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change this code on Codepen https://codepen.io/hkdc/pen/RoJwVX to make the buttons have classes instead of IDs. How can I accomplish this?

I have for example tried to change `id="play"` to `class="play"` in the HTML-file, from `#play` to `.play` in the CSS-file and from `#play` to `.play` in the js file - without any success.

Html:

```
<div class=buttons>
  <button id=play></button> &nbsp;
  <button id=pause></button> &nbsp;
  <button id=stop></button>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#play {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/play.svg);
}

#play.played {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/play1.svg);
}

#pause {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/pause.svg);
}

#pause.paused {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/pause1.svg);
}

#stop {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/stop.svg);
}

#stop.stopped {
    background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/stop1.svg);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    onload = function() {
    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) with(speechSynthesis) {

        var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
        var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
        var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
        var flag = false;

        playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
        pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
        stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

        function onClickPlay() {
            if (!flag) {
                flag = true;
                utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('article').textContent);
                utterance.voice = getVoices()[0];
                utterance.onend = function() {
                    flag = false;
                    playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                    stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                };
                playEle.className = 'played';
                stopEle.className = '';
                speak(utterance);
            }
            if (paused) { /* unpause/resume narration */
                playEle.className = 'played';
                pauseEle.className = '';
                resume();
            }
        }

        function onClickPause() {
            if (speaking && !paused) { /* pause narration */
                pauseEle.className = 'paused';
                playEle.className = '';
                pause();
            }
        }

        function onClickStop() {
            if (speaking) { /* stop narration */
                /* for safari */
                stopEle.className = 'stopped';
                playEle.className = pauseEle.className = '';
                flag = false;
                cancel();

            }
        }

    }

    else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
        msg = document.createElement('h5');
        msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
        msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
        msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        msg.style.color = 'white';
        msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
        document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
    }

}
```

Comment: The pen is not working with the IDs. Maybe fix that first?

Comment: Hmm... That's strange. It is originally from this website: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/text-to-speech/ - maybe that helps?

Comment: You need to learn how to format a question. You had mixed code of all the three languages.

Comment: Curiosity: when we open the codepen link, it shows that you can't use `with` argument when on `'use strict'`. I think that codepen runs the snippets under strict mode and maybe this is causing the issue

Comment: You are certainly right! My bad, really. Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinNunes I was thinking the same thing!!

Answer (score 1):

It was not working for you because you did not observed the code carefully. The code was clearing the **className** i.e `play.className = ''`  instead you have to use **classList** property of the **HTMLelement**. Hope this helps you.

```js
onload = function() {
 if ('speechSynthesis' in window) with(speechSynthesis) {

  var playEle = document.querySelector('.play');
  var pauseEle = document.querySelector('.pause');
  var stopEle = document.querySelector('.stop');
  var flag = false;

  playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
  pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
  stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

  function onClickPlay() {
   if (!flag) {
    flag = true;
    utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(document.querySelector('article').textContent);
    utterance.voice = getVoices()[0];
    utterance.onend = function() {
     flag = false;
     playEle.classList.remove('played');
     stopEle.classList.add('stopped');
    };
    playEle.classList.add('played');
    stopEle.classList.remove('stopped');
    speak(utterance);
   }
   if (paused) { /* unpause/resume narration */
    playEle.classList.add('played');
    pauseEle.classList.remove('pasused');
    resume();
   }
  }

  function onClickPause() {
   if (speaking && !paused) { /* pause narration */
    pauseEle.classList.add('paused');
    playEle.classList.remove('played');
    pause();
   }
  }

  function onClickStop() {
   if (speaking) { /* stop narration */
    /* for safari */
    stopEle.classList.add('stopped');
    playEle.classList.remove('played');
        pauseEle.classList.remove('paused');
    flag = false;
    cancel();

   }
  }

 }

 else { /* speech synthesis not supported */
  msg = document.createElement('h5');
  msg.textContent = "Detected no support for Speech Synthesis";
  msg.style.textAlign = 'center';
  msg.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  msg.style.color = 'white';
  msg.style.marginTop = msg.style.marginBottom = 0;
  document.body.insertBefore(msg, document.querySelector('div'));
 }

}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text');
html {
 font-size: 16pt;
 font-family: crimson text;
}

article {
 width: 60%;
 margin: auto;
}

blockquote,
div,
h1 {
 text-align: center;
}

blockquote {
 font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.buttons {
 margin-top: 25px;
}

button {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 48px;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0;
 width: 48px;
}

.play {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/play.svg);
}

.play.played {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/play1.svg);
}

.pause {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/pause.svg);
}

.pause.paused {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/pause1.svg);
}

.stop {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/stop.svg);
}

.stop.stopped {
 background-image: url(https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/stop1.svg);
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
 html {
  font-size: 14pt;
 }
 article {
  width: 90%;
 }
}

body {
 margin: 0;
}


/*  demo decor */

#-demo-title {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: #D5FFD1;
 color: #0F316C;
 line-height: 36px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16pt;
 text-align: center;
}

#-demo-profile {
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: .4;
}

#-demo-profile:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
 #-demo-title {
  font-size: 12pt;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class=buttons>
 <button class=play></button> &nbsp;
 <button class=pause></button> &nbsp;
 <button class=stop></button>
</div>
<article>
 <h1>The Hare With Many Friends</h1>
 <img src="https://rpsthecoder.github.io/js-speech-synthesis/hare-and-friends.jpg" width="100%" style="margin: auto;filter: brightness(1.2);">
 <p>A hare was very popular with the other beasts who all claimed to be her friends. But one day she heard the hounds approaching and hoped to escape them by the aid of her many friends. So she went to the horse, and asked him to carry her away from the hounds on his back.</p>
 <p>But he declined, stating that he had important work to do for his master. “He felt sure,” he said, “that all her other friends would come to her assistance.” She then applied to the bull, and hoped that he would repel the hounds with his horns. The bull
  replied: “I am very sorry, but I have an appointment with a lady; but I feel sure that our friend the goat will do what you want.” </p>
 <p>The goat, however, feared that his back might do her some harm if he took her upon it. The ram, he felt sure, was the proper friend to apply to. So she went to the ram and told him the case. </p>
 <p>The ram replied: “Another time, my dear friend. I do not like to interfere on the present occasion, as hounds have been known to eat sheep as well as hares.” The Hare then applied, as a last hope, to the calf, who regretted that he was unable to help
  her, as he did not like to take the responsibility upon himself, as so many older persons than himself had declined the task. By this time the hounds were quite near, and the Hare took to her heels and luckily escaped.</p>
 <blockquote>Moral of the story: He that has many friends, has no friends.</blockquote>
</article>
```

Comment: Nice catch! To be more precise, when the OP switches the IDs to classes on the button elements, a `<button>` element will have two classes instead of one. Using `className` removes **all** classes. When IDs are used, there is only ever one class and `className` works.

Comment: after clearing the className, the play button was not removed from the DOM but the CSS rules were removed instead because the CSS rules where only applied to element with class play.

Comment: @Kashma if you like my solution to your problem you give a upvote to my answer. :)